# Merge conflict in git using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

Hi I am facing a merge conflict using git in eclipse.

Basically I am trying to synch two branches i.e branch A and branch B. So while synching Branch B with branch A conflicts occurred. Hence to resolve these conflicts all the files have been marked as merged and has been committed and pushed.

But again while synching with branch B with branch A the same files are shown in conflicts mode with no changes shown in files diff..

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you did and what happened? Maybe show your output?

Comment: I was synchronizing branch FET with the REL branch, and want to have same changes in FET branch as there in REL branch. There are conflicts in 2 files. I merged those files and performed commit & push. Now while again synching the FET branch with REL branch I'm getting the same 2 files in conflict view but there is no diff. How this can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Before merging your changes from branch B(ex: development) to branch A(ex: master), get the latest changes from the branchA  to branchB and resolve the conflicts

```
 $ git checkout branchB  # Ignore this if you've already in the branchB

 $ git merge branchA  # This will merge recursively and show conflicts if any. so resolve the conflicts and commit on 'branchA"

 $ git commit -m "resolving conflicts and merging from branchA to branchB"

 $ git checkout branchA  # Assuming this is master branch 

 $ git merge branchB  # Now this shouldn't show any conflicts since it's resolved earlier
```

Now branchA and branchB both are having the same changes!

Comment: Can you please tell the same in eclipse.